# 0805 package SMT pads minimum clearance and tombstoning

Tags: led, pcb, pcb-design, heat, pcb-assembly

The picture shows 0805 LEDs and one last 0805 resistor connected to the GND pour.

[image]

- What is the minimum clearance between the SMT pads of the different 0805 LEDs that I should consider safe for assembly?
- Will I have any troubles routing the traces between the LEDs this way other than the 'hard visual inspection', or should I route it that way:

[image]

- What is the best polygon connect style for the last resistor to Gnd to avoid tombstoning and other issues?

Comment: How are these being produced? Are you intending to solder components by hand? Are they being done by a fabricator? Uneven copper mass can cause pads to unevenly heat which can lead to tombstoning; but I would be surprised if your layout causes any such issues. You have fairly equal mass on every pad, and the thermal vias to the ground pour are good.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: They will be assembled by pick N place machine at PCB fabricator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking for is the 'component footyard' which is defined in IPC7351B (soon to be updated… for something like 5 years)

As already answered at the end it boils down to your fabrication capabilities however there are general guidelines for the most common situations. If you are doing class 1, producibility level B (general electronics with normal production yields) as a rule of thumb (for SMD components) you enclose all your copper pads and your body (in the maximum material position i.e. bigger as possible under package tolerances) and add 0.25mm of courtyard all around.

The general idea is that you then place the components so that the courtyards do not overlap (some EDA can check this).

This is a very generalized idea, the standard is actually full of tables with all the numbers (for example for BGA it's recommended to add 2mm all around for reworking). Also the standard is *very* old and many are using the unpublished C revision, but it's a start (unless you are designing, say, a smartwatch).

In general pick and place capabilities are about 0.1mm and layer to mask registration is about 0.2mm, there is a complete statistical analysis in the standard if you want the full story.

As for the pad join: there is no issue on routing them directly, or even entering thru the diagonal, expecially if the pad is squareish. With thin long pads like for SOPs it's slightly better to enter from the thin side but only to avoid delamination if you need to rework.

Comment: Thanks, Lorenzo for the really helpful Answer. For the last point you mentioned, I came across this article by Altium, where there is an image that illustrates that this routing style is not preferred due to 'component rotation' https://resources.altium.com/p/top-5-pcb-design-guidelines-every-pcb-designer-needs-know#fine-tuning-your-component-placement

Answer (score 2):

Spacing depends on your board fabricator, the pick-and-place technology and your ability to properly label the locations on the silk screen layer (if required by the company that populates the board).

There is no exact answer to such a question.

Comment: What should be considered a safe margin for most board fabricators and assembly houses? No need for silkscreen either.

Comment: I don't use most PCB fabricators, I just use two of them. One insists on 0.254mm between SMD pads and the other allows 0.127mm between pads but pick-n-place tolerances at some prototype houses is not nearly as good as the 0.025mm accuracy of a production house. So, you have to be able to add up possible errors yourself. Also, just because pads can be placed that close doesn't mean they should be placed that close - other factors like solder bridges and component placement accuracy can be an issue.

Comment: @Bavly why the vagueness? Just ask the factory you consider the lowest-cost option. They will give you a number. Use that number. These tolerances scale orders of magnitudes - the factory that assembles iPhone PCBs is not the same as the factory that assembles throwaway LED keychain PCBs.